# How to receive a integer value from database into a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

im trying to receive a integer value (vehicle_number) from DB into a text box, to auto-fill boxes... how can i do it? please

```
using (OdbcConnection conexao = new OdbcConnection(con))
            {
                OdbcCommand commandResgVei = new OdbcCommand(textoResgataVeiculo, conexao);
                conexao.Open();

                OdbcDataReader result = commandResgVei.ExecuteReader();
                resultado.Read();
                vehicle_number.Text = ?????????????????????????? // how?
                name.Text = result["name"] as string;


            }
```

Comment: you want autocomplete textbox or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rdr.Read())
{
     text = rdr["<name>"].ToString();
}
```

If you really need to parse it, then you could try:

```
reader.GetInt32(/*index*/);
```

or:

```
Int32.TryParse(text, out parsedInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
vehicle_number.Text =  result["vehicle_number"]!=null? convert.toString( 
result["vehicle_number"]):"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vehicle_number.Text = result["vehicle_number"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

try it out

```
 vehicle_number.Text=reader.GetInt32(index);
```